# FFMpeg command output shows 'green pixelated' video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to take a single image and add audio resulting in a video playing the entire song with that single image; much like you see for YouTube videos for songs. The command I am using is from this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/868283/image-audio-mp4-how-to-make-video-smaller

This is the command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.png -i song.aac -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 0 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

It works as intended for having the video file be a small size, and the song plays as well, but depending on the image I used, some of the images appear 'Green' when playing the video.

However though, this command works for any image used:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.jpg -i music.mp3 -c copy -shortest output.mp4
```

But the result is a very big file whereas I would like it to be smaller. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

FFMpeg version: 4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you used from the answer you linked to is for YouTube specifically and even says, "your player probably won't like it but YouTube will". I'm assuming you're using a player and not YouTube.

In the same answer is another command under *Widest compatibility for any player*:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i music.mp3 -vf "scale='min(1280,iw)':-2,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -profile:v main -c:a aac -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Try that instead.

Comment: Thank you llogan! That did the trick. Actually earlier today, I tried that command as well and I got the error "width not divisible by 2 (525x866)". I changed the image width to be divisible by 2 after reading your answer and tried again and that (command) did the trick. Prior to all this though, I thought maybe the image I am using was corrupted in some way since it's an edited image, and thought maybe it wasn't readable by ffmpeg.